Question about function exponential, problem easy
In mitosis, a cell divides into two daughter cells. If we consider a complete cycle of mitosis, which usually takes about 24 hours. In a particular experiment, a person pricked their finger where 80 cells were damaged. Considering $\log_{10}{2} \approx 0.3$, approximately how long will it take for the regeneration of these cells starting from one mother cell?
Options:
a) 6.3 days
b) 7.3 days
c) 8.9 days
d) 24 days
e) 40 days
well I arrived at the solution a) 6.3 days I thought of the following formula: $N = N_0 \times 2^{\frac{t}{24}}$ where $80= 2^{\frac{t}{24}}$ Would you like to see how you would solve it? Letter e) 40?

Welcome to stackexchange. This is not a "do my work for me" site. If you [edit] the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck we may be able to help.

This info should be a part of the post, not a comment. Please see how to ask a good question.

You want the answer in days and 24 hours = 1 day - so you just need to solve $2^x=80$

If the population doubles every day starting at $1$, it goes $1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,$ so it reaches $80$ after between $6$ and $7$ days. The exact number of days is the solution to $2^x=80$, which is $x=\log_2(80)\approx6.322$.
